# Phonegap 3.5 - CallbackContext cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have installed an created a `phonegap 3.5` application for `android` in `eclipse kepler`.

After importing I get:

[image]

The errors are:

```
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 966    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 968    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 965    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 966    Java Problem
CallbackContext cannot be resolved to a type    FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 939    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 963    Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved  FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 537    Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved  FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 867    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 362    Java Problem
CallbackContext cannot be resolved to a type    FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 536    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 344    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 362    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 334    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 344    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 322    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 334    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 995    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 995    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 992    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 992    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 983    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 983    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 977    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 977    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 972    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 972    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 971    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 969    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 969    Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView cannot be resolved FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 31 Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult cannot be resolved   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 32 Java Problem
CordovaPlugin cannot be resolved to a type  FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 52 Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved to a variable    FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 115    Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext cannot be resolved    FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 28 Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface cannot be resolved   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 29 Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin cannot be resolved  FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 30 Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 281    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 281    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 312    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 292    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 263    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 263    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 272    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 272    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 248    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 248    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 255    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 255    Java Problem
CordovaWebView cannot be resolved to a type FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 150    Java Problem
CordovaInterface cannot be resolved to a type   FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 150    Java Problem
CallbackContext cannot be resolved to a type    FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 246    Java Problem
The method remapUri(Uri) of type FileUtils must override or implement a supertype method    FileUtils.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 221    Java Problem
CordovaActivity cannot be resolved to a type    NewApp.java /NewApp/src/com/example/NewApp  line 31 Java Problem
Config cannot be resolved   NewApp.java /NewApp/src/com/example/NewApp  line 33 Java Problem
CordovaActivity cannot be resolved to a type    NewApp.java /NewApp/src/com/example/NewApp  line 25 Java Problem
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type NewApp must override or implement a supertype method    NewApp.java /NewApp/src/com/example/NewApp  line 28 Java Problem
CordovaActivity cannot be resolved to a type    NewApp.java /NewApp/src/com/example/NewApp  line 30 Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 385    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 385    Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved or is not a field    Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 353    Java Problem
CallbackContext cannot be resolved to a type    Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 385    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 400    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 400    Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved or is not a field    Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 393    Java Problem
CallbackContext cannot be resolved to a type    Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 400    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 411    Java Problem
webView cannot be resolved  Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 428    Java Problem
CallbackContext cannot be resolved to a type    Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 411    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 411    Java Problem
PluginManager cannot be resolved to a type  Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 432    Java Problem
webView cannot be resolved  Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 431    Java Problem
CordovaPlugin cannot be resolved to a type  Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 256    Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved or is not a field    Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 256    Java Problem
CordovaPlugin cannot be resolved to a type  Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 239    Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved or is not a field    Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 239    Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved or is not a field    Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 294    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 287    Java Problem
CordovaResourceApi cannot be resolved to a type ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 324    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 287    Java Problem
CallbackContext cannot be resolved to a type    Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 287    Java Problem
CordovaResourceApi cannot be resolved to a type ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 229    Java Problem
LOG cannot be resolved  Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 319    Java Problem
CordovaInterface cannot be resolved to a type   ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 257    Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved or is not a field    Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 317    Java Problem
CordovaResourceApi cannot be resolved to a type ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 211    Java Problem
LOG cannot be resolved  Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 315    Java Problem
CordovaResourceApi cannot be resolved to a type ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 229    Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved or is not a field    Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 313    Java Problem
CordovaResourceApi cannot be resolved to a type ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 206    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a variable   Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 342    Java Problem
CordovaResourceApi cannot be resolved to a type ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 206    Java Problem
PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 342    Java Problem
CordovaResourceApi cannot be resolved to a type ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 185    Java Problem
CallbackContext cannot be resolved to a type    Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 342    Java Problem
CordovaResourceApi cannot be resolved to a type ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 205    Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved or is not a field    Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 325    Java Problem
CordovaResourceApi cannot be resolved to a type ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 70 Java Problem
PluginManager cannot be resolved to a type  ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 65 Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext cannot be resolved    AudioHandler.java   /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/media    line 21 Java Problem
CordovaInterface cannot be resolved to a type   ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 141    Java Problem
CordovaResourceApi cannot be resolved to a type ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 70 Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext cannot be resolved    Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 34 Java Problem
PluginManager cannot be resolved to a type  ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 54 Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult cannot be resolved   AudioHandler.java   /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/media    line 31 Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin cannot be resolved  Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 35 Java Problem
CordovaPlugin cannot be resolved to a type  AudioHandler.java   /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/media    line 47 Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.LOG cannot be resolved    Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 36 Java Problem
PluginManager cannot be resolved to a type  ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 57 Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.PluginManager cannot be resolved  Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 37 Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin cannot be resolved  AudioHandler.java   /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/media    line 22 Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult cannot be resolved   Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 38 Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.CordovaResourceApi cannot be resolved AudioHandler.java   /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/media    line 23 Java Problem
CordovaInterface cannot be resolved to a type   ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 49 Java Problem
CordovaPlugin cannot be resolved to a type  Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 54 Java Problem
CordovaResourceApi cannot be resolved to a type ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 47 Java Problem
CallbackContext cannot be resolved to a type    Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 71 Java Problem
CordovaInterface cannot be resolved to a type   ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 51 Java Problem
CallbackContext cannot be resolved to a type    Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 88 Java Problem
CordovaWebView cannot be resolved to a type ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 49 Java Problem
CallbackContext cannot be resolved to a type    Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 89 Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved to a variable    Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 141    Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView cannot be resolved ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 32 Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved or is not a field    Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 205    Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.CordovaResourceApi cannot be resolved ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 31 Java Problem
CordovaPlugin cannot be resolved to a type  Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 205    Java Problem
CordovaInterface cannot be resolved to a type   ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 46 Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved  Capture.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 212    Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.PluginManager cannot be resolved  ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 33 Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface cannot be resolved   ContentFilesystem.java  /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 30 Java Problem
CordovaInterface cannot be resolved to a type   FileHelper.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 91 Java Problem
CordovaInterface cannot be resolved to a type   FileHelper.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 146    Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface cannot be resolved   FileHelper.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 25 Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.LOG cannot be resolved    FileHelper.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 26 Java Problem
LOG cannot be resolved  FileHelper.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 61 Java Problem
CordovaInterface cannot be resolved to a type   FileHelper.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 79 Java Problem
CordovaInterface cannot be resolved to a type   FileHelper.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 46 Java Problem
LOG cannot be resolved  FileHelper.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 56 Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface cannot be resolved   LocalFilesystem.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 34 Java Problem
CordovaInterface cannot be resolved to a type   LocalFilesystem.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 45 Java Problem
CordovaInterface cannot be resolved to a type   LocalFilesystem.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 47 Java Problem
CordovaInterface cannot be resolved to a type   LocalFilesystem.java    /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 50 Java Problem
CordovaInterface cannot be resolved to a type   FileHelper.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 46 Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.LOG cannot be resolved    FileHelper.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 26 Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface cannot be resolved   FileHelper.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 25 Java Problem
CordovaInterface cannot be resolved to a type   FileHelper.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 91 Java Problem
CordovaInterface cannot be resolved to a type   FileHelper.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 79 Java Problem
LOG cannot be resolved  FileHelper.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 61 Java Problem
LOG cannot be resolved  FileHelper.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 56 Java Problem
CordovaInterface cannot be resolved to a type   FileHelper.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 146    Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved to a variable    CameraLauncher.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 785    Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved or is not a field    CameraLauncher.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 867    Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved or is not a field    CameraLauncher.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 921    Java Problem
CallbackContext cannot be resolved to a type    CameraLauncher.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 950    Java Problem
CallbackContext cannot be resolved to a type    CameraLauncher.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 967    Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface cannot be resolved   FileHelper.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 24 Java Problem
CordovaInterface cannot be resolved to a type   FileHelper.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture line 50 Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved or is not a field    CameraLauncher.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 975    Java Problem
LOG cannot be resolved  CameraLauncher.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 983    Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved to a variable    CameraLauncher.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 771    Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved to a variable    CameraLauncher.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 765    Java Problem
LOG cannot be resolved  CameraLauncher.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 748    Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved or is not a field    CameraLauncher.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 746    Java Problem
LOG cannot be resolved  CameraLauncher.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 744    Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved or is not a field    CameraLauncher.java /NewApp/src/org/apache/cordova/camera   line 742    Java Problem
cordova cannot be resolved or is not a field    CameraLauncher.java /NewApp/src/org
```

I also found that this error could be resolved by adding `CordovaLib/src` folder of the current project. How to do that?

How to resolve this error?

I appreciate your answer

Comment: If you are trying to compile your Android app, you shouldn't import the Cordova project into Eclipse. Simply work with the files in your project `/www` directory and compile it with the following command `cordova run android`.

Comment: @JamesWong THx for your answer! However, eclipse does this automatic. How can I just work with the files in the `www` directory inside of eclipse?

Comment: Am not sure how you are doing it but starting with Cordova Phonegap 3.0, Eclipse is not longer used. You should follow the instruction posted by Adobe PhoneGap team http://phonegap.com/install/